# Error while creating calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-columns, data-analysis, case-statement, bi-tool

I have a Baseball Player Data file. I want to create a calculated column called "Quadrant" which will categorise the types of players into 4 categories. 
My code is:

```
CASE 

WHEN ([OBP]<=PERCENTILE([OBP],50)) AND ([BB/K]<=PERCENTILE([BB/K],50))
THEN "Banjo Hitter"
WHEN ([OBP]<=PERCENTILE([OBP],50)) AND ([BB/K]>PERCENTILE([BB/K],50))
THEN "Patient Hitter"
WHEN ([OBP]>PERCENTILE([OBP],50)) AND ([BB/K]<=PERCENTILE([BB/K],50))
THEN "Solid Hitter"
WHEN ([OBP]>PERCENTILE([OBP],50)) AND ([BB/K]>PERCENTILE([BB/K],50))
THEN "Top Performer"
END
```

here OBP and BB/K are calculated fields. The 50th percentile is the median.
I am getting an error that says "Syntax error: maybe you are missing an identifier".
Can anyone help me figure out what my mistake is? I am new to tableau and practicing examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentile expression can be as per below image:

[image]

The below calculation is valid.

```
IF [OBP]<= { FIXED : PERCENTILE([OBP],0.50) }AND [BB/K]<= { FIXED :PERCENTILE([BB/K],0.50)}
    THEN "Banjo Hitter"

    ELSEIF  [OBP]<= { FIXED :PERCENTILE([OBP],0.50)} AND [BB/K]>{ FIXED :PERCENTILE([BB/K],0.50)}
    THEN "Patient Hitter"

    ELSEIF [OBP]> { FIXED :PERCENTILE([OBP],0.50)} AND [BB/K]<={ FIXED :PERCENTILE([BB/K],0.50)}
    THEN "Solid Hitter"

    ELSEIF [OBP]> { FIXED :PERCENTILE([OBP],0.50)} AND [BB/K]>{ FIXED :PERCENTILE([BB/K],0.50)}
    THEN "Top Performer"

    END
```

Also for reference [Click Here](https://www.interworks.com/blog/wjones/2015/08/14/percentile-distributions-dimension-tableau)

Comment: Thank you for the answer..I changed the percentile value from 50 to 0.50..then I added ATTR  to get dimension value at the sum level. But I could only create 1 category "Banjo hitter". Others are not getting created.

Comment: Place it as a dimension not as attribute.

Comment: Worked!! Thanks a lot ..:)

Comment: No Problem...:)